# Payment Offline missing on contribution Page

Tags: joomla, paylater

I have a brand new installation of Civicrm on a Joomla 3.2.7 site.
When I set up a Contribution page I told it to accept Credit Cards and Offline Payments. The Credit Card shows up, but not the Offline payment.
You can see it here:
https://events.toastmastersd47.org/en/ads

Is there a setting in the administrator area that I need to set as well?

Comment: when you say offline payment are you referring to pay later?

Comment: yes. The documentation says Offline payment, so that is why I used that instead.

Comment: please enable the pay later option in manage contribution page - and try the same

Comment: It is fully enabled in the Manage Contribution screen with a label and instructions set up.

Comment: http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2

Comment: please make sure you have the same setting against your contribution page - http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/contribute/settings&reset=1&action=update&id=2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "Same setting against your contribution page"  On the Amounts tab, I have checked Credit Card and Pay Later Option.  I have filled in the Pay Later label and instructions.  Is there another screen where I need to set this information?  I cannot find it mentioned any place else.

Comment: Yes I was mentioning about contribution page - if you have done then it ok - please try to change the theme once and try displaying the page

Comment: Do you have the methods of "Offline payment" set up and enabled in Administer>CiviContribute>Payment Methods?  If not then you need to do so before they will appear in your conribution page.
If you haven't read the CiviCRM guide, a link to creating contribution pages is here at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/contributions/online-contributions/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a problem with your theme.

I am not seeing the total amount show when you select a sponsorship level. The images for the credit cards and Empowered by CiviCRM are also missing.

Comment: I didn't even realize that was missing. :(  Is there maybe a section that didn't install correctly?  I didn't get any errors on install.

Comment: It may not be a CiviCRM install issue, but your Joomla theme that's causing the problems.

Comment: I used an Artisteer generated theme.  Can you think of anything specific I should look at in the template?